# Shading areas between nodes in different lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code I shaded areas with separate \draw or \path commands. Is there a way to shade these areas between the nodes in different lines directly from within the drawn dotted lines commands; to avoid redefining their coordinates.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (7.6,0) node [black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] {Q};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,7) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.2cm] {P};

\draw [ultra thin, red!30!white, fill=red!30!white] (2.,4.14) -- ++(-90:1.14) -- +(0:2.);
\path[fill=red] (2.,3.) -- ++(-90:1.14) -- +(30:2.3);

\draw [very thick, blue] (4.,3.) +(-30:2.6cm) -- +(150:4.6cm)  +(30:2.6cm) -- +(-150:4.6cm);

\draw [very thick, red] (.2,3.1) -- +(30:5.cm);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.14) node [black, xshift=-.28cm, yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_B$} -- +(0:2.) node [circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{};

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,3.) node [black, xshift=-.28cm, yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_1$} -- ++(0:4.) node [circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{} --+(-90:3);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,1.84) node [black, xshift=-.28cm, yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_S$} -- ++(0:2.) node [circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{} --+(-90:1.84) ;

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (2.,4.14) -- +(-90:2.23) node [pos=.5,circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `coordinate` nodes are for. Please, read ["A Picture for Karl’s Students"](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=29) and ["Euclid’s Amber Version of the Elements"](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=58), they are easy to read and understand. You will solve all this kind of problems with `TikZ`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (7.6,0) node [black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] {Q};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,7) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.2cm] {P};

\coordinate (a) at (2,4.14);
\coordinate (b) at (2,3);
\coordinate (c) at (2,1.86);
\coordinate (d) at (4,3);

\draw [ultra thin, red!30!white, fill=red!30!white] (a) -- (b) -- (d) -- cycle;

\path[fill=red] (c) -- (b) --(d) --cycle;

\draw [very thick, blue] (4.,3.) +(-30:2.6cm) -- +(150:4.6cm)  +(30:2.6cm) -- +(-150:4.6cm);

\draw [very thick, red] (.2,3.1) -- +(30:5.cm);

\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (a-|0,0) node [left] {$P_B$} -| (a|-0,0); 
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (d-|0,0) node [left] {$P_1$} -| (d|-0,0); 
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (c-|0,0) node [left] {$P_S$} -| (c|-0,0); 

\foreach \i in {a,b,c,d}
    \path[fill=black] (\i) circle(3pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]