# Shading areas between nodes in different lines, with node definition within \draw commands

Tags: tikz-pgf

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445266/shading-areas-between-nodes-in-different-lines) I`ve got a good answer, which defined separate coordinates for points to shade an area between them.

Is it possible to define these coordinates as nodes within the \draw commands in my original question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (7.6,0) node [black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] {Q};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,7) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.2cm] {P};
\path[fill=red!30!white] (2.,4.14) -- (2,1.84) -- (4,3.);
\draw [very thick, blue] (4.,3.) +(-30:2.6cm) -- +(150:4.6cm)  +(30:2.6cm) -- +(-150:4.6cm);
\draw [very thick, red] (.2,3.1) -- +(30:5.cm);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.14) node [black, xshift=-.28cm, yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_B$} -- ++(0:2.) node [circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{} -- +(-90:4.14);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,3.) node [black, xshift=-.28cm, yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_1$} -- ++(0:4.) node [circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{} --+(-90:3);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,1.84) node [black, xshift=-.28cm, yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_S$} -- +(0:2.) node [circle, draw, solid, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The answer was:

```
\coordinate (a) at (2,4.14);
\coordinate (c) at (2,1.86);
\coordinate (d) at (4,3);
\path[fill=red!30!white] (a) -- (c) --(d) --cycle;
\draw [very thick, blue] (4.,3.) +(-30:2.6cm) -- +(150:4.6cm)  +(30:2.6cm) -- +(-150:4.6cm);
\draw [very thick, red] (.2,3.1) -- +(30:5.cm);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (a-|0,0) node [left] {$P_B$} -| (a|-0,0); 
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (d-|0,0) node [left] {$P_1$} -| (d|-0,0); 
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (c-|0,0) node [left] {$P_S$} -| (c|-0,0);
```

[image]

Comment: The question is what objects should serve as references for the construction ?

Comment: Please do not put an answer in your question. Either post an answer or remove your question if you consider it relevant.

Comment: what is the problem? what you try so far? what is wrong when you use `\coordinate` ?

Comment: I`ve edited my question to show my original question and the suggested answer which I would like to modify.

Comment: I would like to define the nodes within the \draw commands, not separately, to avoid rewriting the coordinates.

Comment: coordinates *are* nodes. You can refer to the center coordinates by using `(<node>.center)`.

Comment: @Hany You can use `coordinate` as inline command similar to how you would use `node` inline (after a `\draw` or `\path` command). You could also use `node[coordinate]`, which yields the same result.

Comment: Would you please give me one example of incorporating the node[coordinate] inline after \draw using one of my \draw commands. Thank you.

Comment: `\node[coordinate] (x) at (0,0);` is (practically) equivalent to `\coordinate (x) at (0,0);`. That is, whenever you wrote `coordinate` so far, you could have used `node[coordinate]` as well as long, of course, the node had no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use the centers of the bullets to define the corners of the shaded regions. To do that, give the bullet nodes names, and refer to their centers with `.center`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (7.6,0) node [black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=0cm] {Q};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,7) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.2cm] {P};
\draw [very thick, blue] (4.,3.) +(-30:2.6cm) -- +(150:4.6cm)  +(30:2.6cm) -- +(-150:4.6cm);
\draw [very thick, red] (.2,3.1) -- +(30:5.cm);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,4.14) node [black, xshift=-.28cm,
yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_B$} -- ++(0:2.) node [circle, draw, solid, black,
fill=black, scale=0.5](x1){}  -- +(-90:4.14);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,3.) node [black, xshift=-.28cm,
yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_1$} -- ++(0:4.) node [circle, draw, solid, black,
fill=black, scale=0.5](x2){}  --+(-90:3);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (0,1.84) node [black, xshift=-.28cm,
yshift=0cm, align=center] {$P_S$} -- +(0:2.) node [circle, draw, solid, black,
fill=black, scale=0.5](x3){};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[fill=red!30!white] (x1.center) -- (x2.center) -- (x3.center)  -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much; that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

well, you already receive answer which is exactly what you want :-), so this answer is for exercise ...

- when i test code which you provide in question, i obtain the same result, so i wonder, what is your problem?
- your code is unnecessary complicated. i suggest you to draw image on similar way as you write latex document: first define style (by loading packages) and than write contet, i.e. at drawing of images first define common style for elements and than write code of image:

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile,t]
  \frametitle{}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
          scale = .9, thick,
              > = latex,
     dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
                   node contents={}},
                          ]
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (7,0) node [black, right] {Q};
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,7) node [black, above] {P};
  %
  \path [fill=red!30!white] (2.,4.14) -- (2,1.84) -- (4,3.);
  %
  \draw [very thick, blue]    (4,3)+(-30:2.6) -- +(150:4.6cm)+(30:2.6) -- +(-150:4.6cm);
  \draw [very thick, red]     (.2,3.1)        -- +(30:5.cm);

  \draw [densely dotted] (0,4.14) node [left] {$P_B$} -| (2,0)  node[dot, pos=0.5];
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,3.00) node [left] {$P_1$} -| (4,0)  node[dot, pos=0.5];
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,1.84) node [left] {$P_S$} -| (2,0)  node[dot, pos=0.5];
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My request was to avoid defining the shaded area coordinates twice, once in the original \draw command, and the other in the \path command. As for your style definition, my document contains a lot of frames with different definitions for latex arrows and circles; so I can not define them globally. Thank you for your concern and answer.

Comment: to define styles globally is fine, however locally is also helpful :-) code is than more clean and shorter.shaded area is in my answer behind lines, as you can see, without use of background layer...